# How to turn this program from an if-else-if statement into a switch statement in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, converters

I'm having trouble turning this program from an if-else-if statement into a switch statement.

```
public void tick() {
    if (s.word == 0)
        return;

    short t = this.sc.word;
    short d = this.get_opcode();
    short i = this.get_indirect_bit();

    if (t == 0 || t == 1)
        this.instruction_fetch(t);

    if (t == 2)
        this.instruction_decode();

    if (t == 3 && d != 7)
        this.operand_fetch(i);

    if (t > 3 && d != 7)
        this.execute_mri(d, t);

    if (t == 3 && d == 7) {
        this.execute_rri((short) (this.ir.word & 0xFFF));
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you *tried* in doing a switch statement that hasn't worked?  As it stands, this is just 'can you write the code for me?'.

Comment: You can't turn `&&` statements into a case condition very easily. You need an if somewhere

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to completely eliminate the "if" statements, but this code should be what you're looking for:

```
if (s.word == 0)
    return;
short t = this.sc.word;
short d = this.get_opcode();
short i = this.get_indirect_bit();

switch(t) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        this.instruction_fetch(t);
        break;
    case 2:
        this.instruction_decode();
        break;
    case 3:
        if(d ==7) {
            this.execute_rri((short) (this.ir.word & 0xFFF));
        }
        else {
            this.operand_fetch(i);
        }
        break;
    default:
        if(d!=7) this.execute_mri(d, t);
        break;
}
```